# github: changing file, adding it and pushing without commit

Tags: git

I m learning git workflow and tried this on my computer:

added line "third change" to jp2.java file

commands I did:

> git add jp2.java
>
> git push

it says "everything up to date"

is it because i forgot to do commit command?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

`push` command only pushes changes which were already committed to local repository.

Answer (score 1):

So lets see where we can begin .

When you start working on a git branch and are adding a new file that did not exist before you have to execute the add command. 
Adding the file stages the file for a commit. To do the commit you have to execute the `git commit` command. On doing the `git commit` the file will be committed to the local branch. After this you can go ahead and push out the branch.